# при смене select в передать значения input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<form method="POST" action="https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml">

  <!-- ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫЕ ПОЛЯ -->
  <input type="hidden" name="shopId" value="впишите-сюда-значение-своего-shopId">
  <input type="hidden" name="scid" value="впишите-сюда-значение-своего-scid">Телефон клиента<font color="red">*</font>:
  <br>
  <input type=text name="cps_phone" size="64" placeholder="+79031234567 - это пример ввода">
  <br>
  <br>Идентификатор клиента<font color="red">*</font>:
  <br>
  <input type=text name="customerNumber" size="64" placeholder="клиент N2 - это пример">
  <br>
  <br>Сумма (руб.)<font color="red">*</font>:
  <br>
  <input type=text name="sum" size="64">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input name="paymentType" value="" type="hidden" />

  <!-- Необязательные поля -->
  Ф.И.О.:
  <br>
  <input type=text name="custName" size="43">
  <br>
  <br>Адрес доставки:
  <br>
  <input type=text name="custAddr" size="43">
  <br>
  <br>E-mail:
  <br>
  <input type=text name="custEmail" size="43">
  <br>
  <br>Содержание заказа:
  <br>
  <textarea rows="10" name="orderDetails" cols="34"></textarea>
  <br>
  <br>

  <!-- Кнопка отправки платежа -->
  <input type=submit value="Оплатить">
  <br>
</form>
```

Подключаю Яндекс Кассу
 
есть сайт
 
есть 3 товара
 
цены на них разные
 
прислали такую форму, но хочеться доработать
 
чтобы был select
 
и при его смене
 
менялась цена

```
Сумма (руб.)<font color="red">*</font>:<br> 
<input type=text name="sum" size="64"><br><br>
<input name="paymentType" value="" type="hidden"/>
```

а вместо

```
Содержание заказа:<br>
<textarea rows="10" name="orderDetails" cols="34"></textarea><br><br>
```

простой текст, а он уже тянул значение из select

https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/payment-solution/payment-form/payment-form-email-docpage/

Comment: я так понял - надо делать обработку селекта на ончейндж. 
и скрыть input type=text name="sum".
проверять - если выбран 1 - то value суммы равно цене 1.
и так далее. 
то же самое сделать с textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `<head>` подключите JQuery и напишите следующую функцию
И немного переделайте форму, на `select` вешаете вызов функции при изменении получаете сумму и вставляете в `input` с `id="sum"`

```html
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function ChangeSum(){
      var sum = $('#goods').val();
      $('#sum').val(sum);
     }
    </script>
    <form method="POST" action="https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml">
        
          <!-- ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫЕ ПОЛЯ -->
          <input type="hidden" name="shopId" value="впишите-сюда-значение-своего-shopId">
          <input type="hidden" name="scid" value="впишите-сюда-значение-своего-scid">Телефон клиента<font color="red">*</font>:
          <br>
          <input type=text name="cps_phone" size="64" placeholder="+79031234567 - это пример ввода">
          <br>
          <br>Идентификатор клиента<font color="red">*</font>:
          <br>
          <input type=text name="customerNumber" size="64" placeholder="клиент N2 - это пример">
          <br>
          <br>Товар
          <br>
          <select id="goods" onChange="ChangeSum()">
         <option value="100">Товар 1</option>
         <option value="200">Товар 2</option>
         <option value="300">Товар 3</option>
         <option value="400">Товар 4</option>
         <option value="500">Товар 5</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <br>Сумма (руб.)<font color="red">*</font>:
          <br>
          <input type=text name="sum" size="64" id="sum">
          <br>
          <br>
          <input name="paymentType" value="" type="hidden" />
        
          <!-- Необязательные поля -->
          Ф.И.О.:
          <br>
          <input type=text name="custName" size="43">
          <br>
          <br>Адрес доставки:
          <br>
          <input type=text name="custAddr" size="43">
          <br>
          <br>E-mail:
          <br>
          <input type=text name="custEmail" size="43">
          <br>
          <br>Содержание заказа:
          <br>
          <textarea rows="10" name="orderDetails" cols="34"></textarea>
          <br>
          <br>
        
          <!-- Кнопка отправки платежа -->
          <input type=submit value="Оплатить">
          <br>
        </form>
```

Comment: Спасибо! остальное я допилю, мне главное было получить синтаксис и логику данного действия!